# Hit by the spam detector on Travel.SE

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, spam, spam-detection

I want to edit [this answer of mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66617/12141) on Travel.SE to add a paragraph about how to purchase a certain kind of train ticket in Japan, and I am hit by the spam detector. A screenshot of the added section follows. My guess for why it is rejected is that it contains a fair amount of Chinese characters (which are also used in Japan) which I include for reference to assist communication between a non-Japanese-speaking traveler and a ticket office clerk. If this is the case, I believe this is a problem with the spam detector and not with my answer, as this is not an unreasonable thing to post on a travel-related website.

---

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow, it's striking how much this looks like common spam. :P

Comment: My spam detector is going off right now.  In fact, I might flag this question as spam.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are enabled and disabled frequently to deal with large waves of incoming spam.

I've disabled it for now to allow you to post your answer; it may be re-enabled if needed.

Comment: @fkraiem [Here's a sample of the spam posts this block targets](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/reason/59).  Note that a bot recently went through the list of sites posting on each one; it actually got stuck for a couple of hours when it tried to post to Travel.